# Show that $S(n)\leq5\log_2(2n)+7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

I'm asked to show that for any positive integer n, we have: $S(n)\leq 5\log_2(2n)+7$

Where $S(n)$ is a total function (spans from positive integers to real integers),

such that $S(1) = 7$, and 
$S(2^k) = S(2^{k-1})+5$

$S(n) \leq 5\log_2(2n)+7$

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. I'm not sure a proof by induction would be viable here (Don't think that's what the questions wants me to do). And I'm not sure if I can simply just plug in values, and show that positives values for n work in that sense? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: I haven't but I'm not sure if I'm so posed to, my teacher is usually explicit in questions when he asks for induction, then again I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "spans"? Is this how S is defined for non-powers of 2?

Comment: Spans as in, it's a total function from Z+ to R+, S is always non decreasing.

Comment: I finished. Let me know if you want me to finish so that you can verify

Comment: It's the "non-decreasing" that makes it possible to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first determine the sequence for $S(n)=S(2^k)$. By knowing that $S(1)=7$ and $2^0=1$, we can find a way to determine the sequence for $S(n)$ using the recursive sequence $S(2^k)=S(2^{k-1})+5$ for which $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (note that we are using $k$ right now not $n$):

if $k=1$,

$$\begin{align} S(2^1)=S(2^{1-1})+5 \\ S(2)=S(1)+5 \\ S(2)=7+5 \\ =12.\end{align}$$

From know in that now $S(1)=7$ and $S(2)=12$, we are able to form an arithmetic sequence for $S(n)$. If we continued beyond $n=2$ for $S(n)$, we can see that we get this:

if $k=2$,

$$\begin{align} S(2^2)=S(2^{2-1})+5 \\ S(4)=S(2)+5 \\ S(4)=12+5 \\ =17;\end{align}$$

if $k=3$,

$$\begin{align} S(2^3)=S(2^{3-1})+5 \\ S(8)=S(4)+5 \\ S(8)=17+5 \\ =22;\end{align}$$

if $k=4$,

$$\begin{align} S(2^4)=S(2^{4-1})+5 \\ S(16)=S(8)+5 \\ S(16)=22+5 \\ =27.\end{align}$$

We can now see that the sequence for $S(2^k)$ is in the form of $$n_1,n_2,n_4,n_8,n_{16},\cdots$$
and with the values
$$7,12,17,22,27,\cdots.$$

So we can determine a sequence first for $S(2^k)$:

$$d=n_2-n_1=12-7=5$$

$$S(2^k)=n_1+(n-1)d$$
$$S(2^k)=7+(n-1)5$$
$$S(2^k)=5n+2.$$

We can then determine the sequence for $S(n)$ that would make an arithmetic function for $n$ such that since we were using a function of $k$ before this, $n=2^k$:

$$k=\log_2n$$
$$S(\log_2n)=5n+2=S(2^k).$$

To get the pure function for $S(n)$, we must get rid of the "$\log_2$" in the "$S(\log_2n)$" by knowing that the sequence is just transformed:

$$S(\log_2n)=5n+2$$
$$S(n)=5\log_2(n)+2.$$

From this new $S(n)$-equation, we can plug it the inequality and see that it is true for all positive integers $n$:

$$S(n)=5\log_2(n)+2$$
$$\therefore 5\log_2(n)+2\leq5\log_2(2n)+7, \ \forall{n}\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

$\boxed{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: Go ahead and finish it I guess, I'm still trying to understand how a arithmetic sequence is valid here, because I never learned to use it in my class, only summations.

Comment: Ok. i will try to add further explanation of how the arithmetic sequence is valid.

Comment: I'll accept your answer now because I have to go, but if you could later update it to show what to do after you've gotten the formula, that would be great.

Comment: Alright. My answer will be done shortly.

Comment: Done. If you have anymore questions just let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you solve the relation $S(2^k) = S(2^{k-1})+5$, such that you have only one $S$ term. You can do that by substituting $S(2^k)$ recursively.

**Solution:**

$S(2^k) = S(2^{k-1})+5$ or,

$S(2^k) = (S(2^{k-2})+5) + 5$ or,

$S(2^k) = ((S(2^{k-3})+5) + 5) + 5$. This goes on until we reach the "base"

case where $S(2^k) = 5k + S(2^0) = 5k + 7$.

Now we know that any positive real number can be represented by $2^k$; because, we can equate $a = 2^k$, and thereby we can say that $k = log_2(a)$.

So lets put $n = 2^k$ in the expression $S(n)\leq 5\log_2(2n)+7$ to get $S(2^k)\leq 5\log_2(2^{k+1})+7$ which is,

$5k + 7 \leq 5(k+1) + 7$

Now we have the above as our final expression, and I guess it is obviously true, for all positive values of $k$.

**Update:**

@stochasticboy3217, you are right. But taking  closer look at the problem shows that there isn't enough information to conclude the answer for it, because, the information $S(2^k)=S(2^{k−1})+5$ only shows how the function behaves for a discreet domain region. The only given base condition is, $S(1) = 7$, but to be able to arrive at a relation for the domain $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the given information is not enough (as here the domain is $1, 2, 4, 8, 16,...$). Note that, unless we have a complete relation for $S(n), n\in (0, 1]$, as a given function we cannot conclude the answer.

$S(k)=5k + 7$ is only valid for **positive integer** values of $k$. But becomes invalid if we assign a non-integer value for $k$. The reason is, the main information we exploit to find this answer is $S(2^k) = S(2^{k-1})+5$. Here, if we consider $k$ to *not* be a positive integer, then we can never arrive at the base case, and the given base condition $S(1) = 7$ is no longer useful. Because, as @stochasticboy3217 pointed out, if we choose $k=1.584$ or something, we can never arrive at the result. So there is literally no logical way to determine $S(k)$, without involving the term $S(2^{k−1})$.

But we can easily arrive at a result which holds for the interval $k = 2^n, \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which is same as the result I came up with: $5k + 7 \leq 5(k+1) + 7$.

So we finally have, $S(2^k) = 5k + f(k)$, where $f(k)$ denotes $S(frac(k))$ for values of $k\in (0, 1)$ and $f(1) = 7 = S(1)$ (as given). Here, $frac(.)$ represents the fractional part.

So we cannot know the answer unless $f(k)$ for the fractional part is defined.

Comment: There's an issue with this, which may be resolved with a bit of thought: You've only shown that $S(2^k) = 5k + 7$ for positive integers $k$. For example, running through your argument for $k=1.5$, $S(2^{1.5}) = 5 + S(2^{0.5})$, the value of the latter being unknown.

Edit: I'm aware that $k = 1.5$ may not be in the domain, that was just for illustration. You might want to put $k = \log_2 3$, though.

Comment: I agree with @stochasticboy321

Comment: Thanks for telling me this, I'll take a look at it. And one more thing, the question doesn't give us enough information to obtain the function $S(k)$ in a simple form, for all real positive integer domain.